# PHP/SQL Sum total customer count

Tags: php, mysql

My database has duplicates for different reasons, and I am trying to get a total of unique customers per a users ID.

This is the current query that I have constructed.

```
    $ApprovedCustomerCount ="SELECT `".Customer_Full_Name."`, `".Customer_Address."`, COUNT(DISTINCT(`".Customer_Full_Name."`)) AS CustomersCount 
                            FROM `".OrdersTable."` 
                            WHERE `".Users_Sales_ID."`=$EMPID
                            AND `".Current_Order_Stage."`='".Current_Order_Stage_Approved."' 
                            GROUP BY `".Customer_Full_Name."`, `".Customer_Address."` 
                            HAVING COUNT(".Customer_Full_Name.") > 1";

    $ApprovedCustomerResult=mysql_query($ApprovedCustomerCount);
    while($OrdersRow=mysql_fetch_array($ApprovedCustomerResult))
    $CustomerApprovedCount = $OrdersRow['CustomersCount'];

    if (empty($CustomerApprovedCount)) { $CustomerApprovedCount = '0'; }    
echo $CustomerApprovedCount;
```

Mistakenly, it only gives me a value of `1` when I echo in PHP.

However, when I query the DB Table with the exact query I get an output ( for each customer name, address that are unique counts = 1) that will display the list of customers, and give me db row count of `67`. That is the number I need.

Query in PhpMyAdmin I run

```
SELECT `CustomerName`, `CustomerAddress`, COUNT(DISTINCT(`CustomerName`)) AS Customers 
FROM `wrightway_orders` 
WHERE `Employee_ID` = '3020'
AND `Order Stage`='Approved'
GROUP BY `CustomerName`, `CustomerAddress` 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Outputs

```
+------------------+----------------------+----------------+
|  Customer Name   |  Address             | CustomersCount |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| ADRIANE JOHNSON  |  10015 161ST PL NE   |        1       |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| BILL SMITH       |  9923 161ST AVE NE   |        1       |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| BRIAN WALTERS    |  11129 106TH AVE NE  |        1       |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------+
```

etc

I need to **sum the total** amount of `Count defined as 'CustomerCount'` values to then echo that value as `echo $CustomerApprovedCount;`

Where am I going wrong?

I appreciate your help :)

I need to count all customers that are unique, then give a sum total of all customers where Employee_ID=ID#.

Comment: please can you clear currently what you got in your necessary parameter and what you need ?

Comment: I have updated my OP with the descrambled sql query. @jilesh

Comment: you need total unique customer count ? am i right ?

Comment: I need to count unique customers, then sum total all customers total

Comment: but you used groupby so it gave you customer count 1 always

Comment: so I would change it to group by CustomerCount would give me the total sum? gives - #1056 - Can't group on 'Customers'

Comment: i mean if you group by with customer name and you use count in customer name it always gives you 1 in count

Comment: i think you will use sub query where you will count customer and use group by in main query

Comment: can you put it in an example? Not sure I am following.

Comment: SELECT `CustomerName`, `CustomerAddress`, (SELECT count(CustomerName) from wrightway_orders WHERE `Employee_ID` = '3020') AS Customers 
FROM `wrightway_orders` 
WHERE `Employee_ID` = '3020'
AND `Order Stage`='Approved'
GROUP BY `CustomerName`, `CustomerAddress` 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: i am not sure this works exactly or not but you will modify it as per your requirement

Comment: Gives me 487 count under Customers for all customers.

Comment: use your condition in inner query how you will get it exactly like : where employee_id = 3020 and order_stage = approved and hope so you will get a count what you need

Comment: nothin. Can you maybe post as an answer what I would need to do exactly?

Comment: yes but please edit your post and set what you need in output in your post

Comment: added to the bottom. of my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `mysql_num_rows` with result:

```
$ApprovedCustomerResult = mysql_query($ApprovedCustomerCount);
$CustomerApprovedCount = mysql_num_rows($ApprovedCustomerResult);
```